# C++ syntax/legality of inheriting from a template while also specifying type

Tags: c++

How can I accomplish what is suggested by the following?:

```
template<typename T>
class Base{...};
...
class Derived : public Base<int>{...};
```

Comment: I don't know if what I described is legal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's legal.

`Base` is a class template, and when provided all its template parameters it can be instantiated, which makes it an instantiated class. So `Base<int>` is a class name, and you can inherit from it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

That looks good.

Answer (score 1):

There's a specific idiom associated with this called static inheritance.

```
template<typename T> class Base {
    void MyStaticVirtualFunction() { T::MSVF(); }
};
class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
    void MSVF();
};
```

In this case Base acts as a base class at compile-time and the function call is resolved statically, but the behaviour of Base can still vary.

Comment: I think it is more known as static polymorphism - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Static_polymorphism